# How can I tell if Ubuntu driver is using integrated graphics GPU to hardware decode HEVC when playing videos using VLC?

Tags: amd-ryzen, integrated, hevc

I've found that VLC uses ~17% CPU for x264 FHD videos, ~28% for HEVC FHD videos, and ~80% for HEVC 4k videos.

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

produces..

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Cezanne
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: c3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=3840,2160
       resources: irq:40 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcc00000-fcc7ffff
```

Processor:  AMD® Ryzen 5 5560u with radeon graphics × 12

Graphics: RENOIR (renoir, LLVM 15.0.6, DRM 3.47, 5.19.0-35-generic)

Answer (score 5):

[To simply cite another site](https://fossbytes.com/enable-hardware-acceleration-vlc-windows-linux-os-x/):

- In `Settings/Preferences`
- **look** for `Input/Codecs` **tab**
- check out the option `Hardware-accelerated decoding`
- select the `Automatic` option and you are fine

( please comment if you have trouble ;) )

Comment: I disabled it and I was still getting ~80% CPU usage playing a HEVC 4k video which leads me to believe it is not using hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 5):

The solution for me was...

```
sudo apt remove vlc
```

then...

```
sudo apt install mpv
```

I now get consistent ~8% CPU usage playing UHD HEVC videos vs. ~80% with VLC.

Comment: No need to remove `vlc`, `mpv` can use hardware acceleration even if VLC is still installed.

Comment: You probably also want to edit `~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf` or `~/.mpv/mpv.conf` with `profile=gpu-hq` and `hwdec=auto` if not already enabled.  I've been using MPV for years, so I don't know how much of my config file is still needed, but I also had to set `hwdec-codecs=hevc,vp8,vp9,mpeg1video,mpeg2video,h264,vc1,wmv3` which is appropriate for my Skylake iGPU.  (I much prefer MPV to VLC anyway, with good key-binds for accurate seeking and single-stepping fwd / backward, and very fast startup from the command line.)

Comment: @pts Simply removing VLC is probably easier than finding out how that particular Linux desktop environment handles file type associations.

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't need to specify hardware decoding in the conf file.  It just did it automatically.

Comment: @deanresin: IIRC, an old version of MPV maybe didn't do it by default for *all* the relevant codecs, like maybe by default for H.264 and H.265, but IIRC it wasn't doing HW decode for VC1 / WMV3 without manual config.  Hopefully that's changed now, and it will HW decode for anything your HW supports.

Comment: Also, `profile=gpu-hq` is a good idea for video quality if your video hardware is fast enough, if the default is only `gpu`.  It'll use a higher-quality scaling algorithm.  (You might need to use a faster scaler for 2160p60 videos, if it can't push that many pixels.)  That's separate from enabling HW decoding.